# Mysql process data by groups

Tags: mysql

I have a few groups of data. Each group has a some `property` field.
For example:

```
_________________________
| id  | value | property |  
--------------------------
| 1    |  2    |    3    |
--------------------------
| 2    |  2    |    3    |
--------------------------
| 3    |  2    |    3    |
--------------------------
| 4    |  2    |    4    |
-------------------------
| 5    |  2    |    4    |
--------------------------
| 6    |  2    |    4    |
--------------------------
```

How can I update two strings ordered by `id ASC` with `property = 3`, and 2 strings ordered by `id ASC` with `property = 4` **by one query?**

I want to update 2 of 3 rows with `property = 3` and update 2 of 3 rows with `property = 4`.  For example: rows with id 1 and 2, and rows with id 4 and 5
i.e. i want update groups of data with different conditions **by one query**

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Can you show what the end-result of the update should be on that data sample? Updating with "ordered by" makes very little sense in SQL .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution, and see discussion following:

```
update 
  t,
  (select GROUP_CONCAT(ids) as matching_ids from (
    select 
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(id order by id), ',', 2) AS ids
    from
      t
    where
      property in (3,4)
    group by
      property
    ) s1
  ) s2
set value=12345
where 
  FIND_IN_SET(id, matching_ids) > 0
;
```

To illustrate, and assuming your table is called `t`, and the initial state is:

```
root@mysql-5.1.51> select * from t;
+----+-------+----------+
| id | value | property |
+----+-------+----------+
|  1 |     2 |        3 |
|  2 |     2 |        3 |
|  3 |     2 |        3 |
|  4 |     2 |        4 |
|  5 |     2 |        4 |
|  6 |     2 |        4 |
+----+-------+----------+
```

The result of running this query is:

```
root@mysql-5.1.51> select * from t;
+----+-------+----------+
| id | value | property |
+----+-------+----------+
|  1 | 12345 |        3 |
|  2 | 12345 |        3 |
|  3 |     2 |        3 |
|  4 | 12345 |        4 |
|  5 | 12345 |        4 |
|  6 |     2 |        4 |
+----+-------+----------+
```

A brief explanation of the query:

I pick up the first two `id`s for each property using the `SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(id order by id), ',', 2)` statement.

I combine the above using `GROUP_CONCAT(ids) as matching_ids` to get all valid `id`s.

Finally, I update all rows in the table where the `id` is within combined `matching_ids` text.

**Notes:**

- You should verify your `group_concat_max_len` variable is long enough. Default is **1024**. You most probably want to have this in the millions, anyhow (regardless of my answer).
- The query is far from being optimal. It answers your question, but you can't have an optimal query here.
- You are most probably better off with a transaction containing two or three queries.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using calculated rank field, e.g. -

```
SELECT p1.*, COUNT(*) rank FROM properties p1
  LEFT JOIN properties p2
    ON p2.property = p1.property AND p2.id <= p1.id
  GROUP BY p1.property, p1.id
```

This query will return dataset with row-number by property:

```
+------+-------+----------+------+
| id   | value | property | rank |
+------+-------+----------+------+
|    1 |     2 |        3 |    1 |
|    2 |     2 |        3 |    2 |
|    3 |     2 |        3 |    3 |
|    4 |     2 |        4 |    1 |
|    5 |     2 |        4 |    2 |
|    6 |     2 |        4 |    3 |
+------+-------+----------+------+
```

Then you should update records with rank < 3:

```
UPDATE properties p
  JOIN (SELECT p1.*, COUNT(*) rank FROM properties p1
          LEFT JOIN properties p2
            ON p2.property = p1.property AND p2.id <= p1.id
        GROUP BY p1.property, p1.id) r
  ON p.id = r.id
  SET p.value = 100 -- set new value here
  WHERE r.rank < 3
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean to limit your two updates to two rows each. You can use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` in your update statements:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET property = 'new_value'
WHERE value=2 AND property = 4
ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 2


UPDATE yourtable
SET property = 'new_value'
WHERE value=2 AND property = 3
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2
```

#### Update:

To force this into one query, you would need to `JOIN` against a subquery which retrieves the ids to update via `UNION`. I *think* this is legal:

```
UPDATE yourtable
  JOIN (
    (SELECT id FROM yourtable WHERE value=2 AND property=4 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 2)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT id FROM yourtable WHERE value=2 AND property=3 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2)
  ) updaterows ON yourtable.id = updaterows.id
SET property = 'new value'
```

Comment: Sorry, i am complete my question: i want one query for this.

Comment: @AndreyVorobyev Why one query? You have two different conditions, why not two queries?

Comment: :i needs make this by sql query, not any script.